# SQL-Data Base defined with list elements

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following problem that I can not solve:
I need a database with 204 parameters. Since I do not want to enter all of them into the init function and later on they might get some, I have created a list and passed it to my init function. Now I want to be flexible also on the basis of the position of my values in the list (l1) configure my database table. The list l1 I have created in another Python document. List 10 is a list of 204 entries whose value is all 0, so that when the database table is created, all values are 0 at the beginning and I can then easily change them afterwards. Then I want to change in another Python file "only" a value, but comes with me the error message:
__init __ () got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'

Below is my code, limited to only one of the 204 parameters

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir,'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
l0=[... , 0, ...]
l1=[... , "email", ...]
class anmeldungtest(db.Model):
    __tabelname__ = "Anmeldung"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.Text)
    def __init__(self, l1=l0):
        self.email = l1[l1.index("email")]
hallo = anmeldungtest(email = "test@gmail.com")
print(hallo.id)
```

Unfortunately, I have no solution to my problem, except to omit the list and write out everything. Can you help me?

(translated from german language)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please ask your question in English!

Comment: okay I´ll thank you!